# How to use stat utility instead of subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath to calculate directory size

Tags: ios, macos, swift, cocoa, stat

I have been calculating directory sizes using `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath::` and have found it very sluggish. After copious amounts of research I came across the `stat` structure that can be used to achieve the desired results more quickly and efficiently. How can I use `stat` in swift to achieve this goal?

Here's my current file size calculation algorithm using `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath::`:

```
func calcSize(pathToDir: String) -> (Int) {
let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var size = 0
    let fileArray = (fm.subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(pathToDir, error: nil)) as! [String]
    for file in fileArray {
        autoreleasepool({
        var fileDict: NSDictionary? = fm.attributesOfItemAtPath(pathToDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file), error: nil)
        size += Int(fileDict!.fileSize())
        })
    }
    return (size)
}
```

PS. all the results I found so far have answers in objective-c and C but not in swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample usage in Swift:

```
var stat1 : stat  = stat()
var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString
stat(documentsPath.fileSystemRepresentation,  &stat1)
println(stat1.st_size)
```

### EDIT

```
  var stat1 : stat  = stat()
        var size = 0
        let fileArray = (NSFileManager.defaultManager().subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(pathToDir as String, error: nil)) as! [String]
        for file in fileArray {

            var stat1 : stat  = stat()
            var filex =  (pathToDir as String) + "/" +  file as NSString
            stat(filex.fileSystemRepresentation,  &stat1)
            if stat(filex.fileSystemRepresentation,  &stat1) != 0 {
                println("Some error occured ")
            } else {
                println(stat1.st_size)
            }
            size += Int(Double(stat1.st_size))                
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the syntax is perfect! However, the size returned using my method with stat instead of attributesOfItemAtPath is completely inaccurate. I updated my answer above with the new code using stat if you could give it a look that would mean a lot!

Comment: @Jonathan I think you were not creating file path 'filex'  correctly. You need to append 'file' to 'pathToDir' for getting correct path. I have updated my answer. It should work for you now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use `NSFileManager.enumeratorAtURL(_:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:)`.  For the property keys, specify `[NSURLTotalFileSizeKey]` or, perhaps, `[NSURLTotalFileAllocatedSizeKey]` depending on what you're interested in. That will include other forks and file metadata that `stat()` won't.

You then enumerate the items in the directory, getting `NSURL`s for each. You query an individual `NSURL`'s size by using `resourceValuesForKeys()`. (I would suggest using `getResourceValue(_:forKey:)`, but that can be a bit awkward in Swift.)

The advantage of using this form of enumerator is that it can pre-fetch the size property as it enumerates the directory. That should end up being faster than `stat()`. Under the hood, it uses `getdirentriesattr()`, which combines directory enumeration with attribute querying.